# Are larger aircraft inherently better-suited to long-distance flights?

Tags: airliner

Restricting this to larger passenger aircraft, and apart from the greater range made possible by larger fuel tanks, are larger aircraft better-suited to long-distance flights simply in virtue of their size?

Comment: Aerodynamically? Financially? Comfort-wise? Speed-wise? Please try to clarify

Comment: @J.Hougaard Neither ? OP clearly ask if range scale with size.

Comment: @J.Hougaard "Financially"? How is that a property of an aircraft? Speed: as you no doubt already know, the speed of passenger aircraft is mainly determined by the speed of sound with nearly all jets cruising at roughly the same speed regardless of size. If however you know something relevant about the effects of scaling on aerodynamics or passenger comfort, by all means add that to an answer.

Comment: @DanieleProcida It's quite an obvious property from a business (airline) point of view.